# CSS problem in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I've been around and around in circles with this one, almost finished my web page and all good in most browsers except the inevitable IE6! I've been doing some research and found out there is a problem with padding and margin in CSS, and have tried to no avail. Is there someone out there who might be able to help?

[www.theclubnetwork.co.uk](http://www.theclubnetwork.co.uk)

```
body {
    background: #ebf5fc url('../Images/body_bg.jpg') repeat-x 0 0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: blue;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;    
}
#env {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 934px;
    background: url('../Images/env_bg.jpg') repeat-y 0 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 125px 0 0 0;
}
#main {
    width: 934px;
    background:  transparent url('../Images/main_bg.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
#promo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 934px;
    background: url('../Images/promo_bg2.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
#bor {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 5px;
    width: 633px;
    background: url('../Images/bor_bg.gif') repeat-y 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#foot {

    height: 49px;
    width: 912px;
    background: url('../Images/foot_bg.png') no-repeat 0 100%;
    padding: 0 11px 8px 11px;
    color: #506273;
    font-size: 11px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
h4 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#foot a {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #506273;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
#foot div {
    padding: 8px 0 0 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
    line-height: 16px;
}
#logo {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: 279px;
    padding-right:20px;
    top:20px;
    left: 10px; 
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 6;
    background-color: #ffa500;
}
#slow {
    position: relative; 
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 6;
}
.nav {
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 25;
}
* html #welcome {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#welcome {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 297px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 6;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.slogan {
    width: 150px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 17px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.mainslogan {
    width: 150px;
    color: #ffa500;
    font-size: 48px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.sloganmiddle {
    width: 150px;
    color: #ffa500;
    font-size: 21px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.bottomslogan {
    width: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.welcome_text {
    position : relative;
    top: 10px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 6;
    display: block;
}
.our_web {
    position : relative;
    color: #ffa500;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    display:block;
}
a.form {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: blue;
}
a.first_web {
    position : relative;
    color: #0d7acf;
    top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: middle;
    display: inline;
}
p.statement {
    position : relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
}
p.allocated {
    text-align: right;
}
* html .clubreg {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}    
.clubreg {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
.memreg {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    height: auto; 
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
.clubform {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
div.box335 { 
    width: 220px; 
    float: left;
    background: transparent url('../Images/box220_bg_top.gif') no-repeat 0 0; 
}
div.box335in { 
    background: transparent url('../Images/box220_bg_btm.gif') no-repeat bottom left;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
div.box220 { 
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background: transparent url('../Images/box220_bg_top.gif') no-repeat 0 0; 
}
div.box220in { 
    background: transparent url('../Images/box220_bg_btm.gif') no-repeat bottom left; 
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 30px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
div.box267 { 
    width: 267px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background: transparent url('../Images/box267_bg_top.gif') no-repeat 0 0; 
}
div.box267in { 
    background: transparent url('../Images/box267_bg_btm.gif') no-repeat bottom left; 
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
#news {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 287px; 
    height: 165px; 
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 6;
    text-align: left;
    color: #0d7acf;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
div.box454 { 
    width: 454px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background: transparent url('../Images/box454_bg_top.gif') no-repeat 0 0; 
}
div.box454in { 
    background: transparent url('../Images/box454_bg_btm.gif') no-repeat bottom left;
    padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
div.box609 { 
    width: 609px;
    min-height: 340px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background: transparent url('../Images/box609_bg_top.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
div.box609in { 
    background: transparent url('../Images/box609_bg_btm.gif') no-repeat bottom left; 
    min-height: 478px;
    padding: 0px 40px 10px 15px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
div.member_title {
    color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
div.regreasons {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
div.box145 { 
    width: 145px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background: transparent url('../Images/box145_bg_top.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}
div.box145in { 
    background: transparent url('../Images/box145_bg_btm.gif') no-repeat bottom left; 
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/
}
* html .advertising {
    left: 0px;
}
div.advertising {
    position: relative; 
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 168px;
    left: -2px; 
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.memreg2 {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
div.buttonreg {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#faq {
    position : relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align:center;
}
* html #sales {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#sales {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 297px; 
    height: 367px; 
    background-color: #666666;
    z-index: 6;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
#joining {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 297px; 
    height: 535px; 
    background-color: #666666;
    z-index: 6;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}
#control_panel {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 297px; 
    height: 480px;
    background-color: #666666;
    z-index: 6;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}
#minimnu {
    position : relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
#focusContainer {
    width: 190px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #71707f;
    padding: 17px 17px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
#focusContainer a {
    display:block;
    background-color: #383737;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#focusContainer a:hover {
    background-color: #ffa500;
    color: blue;
}
#m1 a, #m2 a, #m3 a,#m4 a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.span {
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#5d5d5d;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
a#selected, a#selected:hover {
    background: #ffa500;
    color: blue;
}
a.newshead  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#leftside {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.rbsworldpay {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width = 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
#clubinfo {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: 225px; 
    height: 120px; 
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#meminfo {
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width: 225px; 
    height: 120px; 
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
.moreinfo {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#bottomlink {
    color: #0d7acf;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0px;
}
a.club_details {
    color: blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: A question like "how can i get the red box to have 10px padding around it?" will definitely get more answers than this one.  Good luck!

Comment: please just hyperlink to such large bodies of text rather than copy/pasting them here - also, go visit quirksmode.org

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be so bad if he used the proper code formatting. It would then go into a scrolling box.

Answer (score 4):

In response to the only question in your post
"Is there someone out there who might be able to help?"

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your HTML has a DOCTYPE, to trigger IE6's standards mode. That's likely to eliminate a lot of CSS craziness (and possibly introduce some other craziness, but there will be less of it and it'll happen in all browsers).

Comment: I've added a DOCTYPE I think that's why it's not as bad as it might have been.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having trouble with different browser behaviour, I'd suggest you use a CCS reset.

Eric Meyer explains well and offers a free example at [meyerweb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). That won't solve all your problems, but would certainly be a good start.

Comment: Might do that, managed to sort out the problem now with a lot of bodging by using *html > #container Not the prettiest of solutions but one that will have to do for now! Thanks for the link to the reset though.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I saw right away.

You don't have a font size set for your h2 in the div `#sales` and IE is using a bigger font size. IE6 uses width and height as suggestions and will expand divs to fit the content.

Your `.box335in` has a width of 220px however your `.member_title` div has a width of 220px plus a right padding of 40px for a total width of 260px. Once again IE6 is expanding the .box335in to fit the wider width.

Comment: I've got it to work, but I think that the suggestions you've given will probably sort out the shabby CSS code that I've put in there to bodge the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't worry about making things compatible with IE6 anymore.

Comment: You're probably right, however I was just about to launch when I sent the webiste out to friends to test. A large majority (shame on them) were using IE6. Wonder how many others are out there?